# cmd command only works after the third time

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a CMD Command and it only works after the third time of execution. I want to open a command which gives me a path after that I want to convert the path and in the end I want to show the input of the file.

Here is my command:

```
@echo off & for /f %A in ('getFilePath') do set string="C:%A" & set newstring=%string:/=\% & type %newstring% & @echo on
```

Comment: What is the `getFilePath` command? Would you consider reformatting this as a .bat script until it is working, then convert it into a one-liner? Please edit the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution i am sure it’s not the best way but it works for me.

```
@echo off & for /f %A in ('getFilePath') do ( set script=%A & call type C:%script:/=\\%) & @ECHO ON
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off & for /f %A in ('getFilePath') do set string="C:%A" & set newstring=%string:/=\% & type %newstring% & @echo on
```

would need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) (also [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35181214/2152082) wouldn't work without delayed expansion), but astonishingly `type "c:/path/file.ext"` works (`type c:/path/file.ext` doesn't), so you can just do:

```
@echo off & @for /f %A in ('getFilePath') do @type "C:%A"  & @echo on
```

(assuming `getFilePath` gives you something like `/path/file.ext`)